# Set @lob column to null with EclipseLink

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink, blob

I'm using EclipseLink to manage an Entity that has a BLOB column stored in an Oracle DB. I need to set the column value to NULL.  Simply setting the entity instance variable to NULL does not work.

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "SERIALIZEDEJBTIMERHANDLE")
private byte[] serializedEjbTimerHandle;
```

What is the correct approach?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error at all.  The column just remains unchanged.

Comment: More info is needed then, like how if any other fields can change on your entity, how it's read in and merged.